# Shaggy God story: Male-female pair left on abandoned world, without memory

Tags: alien-invasion, story-identification

A [Shaggy God](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_God_story) short story I probably read in my youth in the 70's, though the publish date could've been much earlier.  A civilization completely abandons their planet in advance of some alien invasion, but (for reasons I can't recall) leaves behind one young male and female, who are necessarily/willingly mind-wiped by those leaving, to protect said civilization from being followed.

The arriving invaders find the pair useless (torture would be futile) and leave them.  The final scene in the story is clearly an Adam/Eve theme - the pair are left alive on the now-abandoned world. 
(Somehow, I always recall this story when I hear early Genesis "Watcher of the Skies".)

Comment: Any chance that Librivox maintains a history? Music was not a detail I recalled, but it seemed that the alien invasion/pursuit had a certain inevitability/recurrence aspect. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [The Link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59451) by [Alan E. Nourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_E._Nourse). Available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/22876).

Matches the civilization fleeing the invaders, the couple left behind who are tortured, rendered mindless, who then become Adam and Eve.

> The inquisition had been horrible. Their minds had had no concept of such horror, such relentless, racking pain. The blazing lights, the questions screaming in their ears, Frankle's vicious eyes burning in frustration, and their own screams, rising with each question they would not answer until their throats were scorched and they could no longer scream. Finally they reached the limit they could endure, and muttered together the hoarse words that could deliver them. Not words that Frankle could hear, but words to bring deliverance, to blank out their minds like a wet sponge over slate. The hypnotic key clicked into the lock of their minds; their screams died in their brains. Frankle stared at them, and knew instantly what they had done, a technique of memory obliteration known and dreaded for so many thousands of years that history could not remember. As his captives stood mindless before him, he let out one hoarse, agonized scream of frustration and defeat.

....

> Blinking dully, the woman crept into the cave after him. Three thoughts alone filled their empty minds. Not thoughts of Nehmon and his people; to them, Nehmon had never existed, forgotten as completely as if he had never been. No thoughts of the Hunters, either, nor of their unheard-of mercy in leaving them their lives—lives of memoryless oblivion, like animals in this green Jungle-land, but lives nonetheless.
>
> Only three thoughts filled their minds:
>
> It was raining.
>
> They were hungry.
>
> The Saber-tooth was prowling tonight.
>
> They never knew that the link had been forged.

Comment: Bingo! This is surely the story. Plenty here I did NOT recall, or did, incorrectly. Thanks very much!